# How can I find out the file system being used in Windows? Preferably in code

Tags: windows, filesystems

How can I find out the type of file system being used in Windows?  Preferably in code.

Comment: Do you mean with code?  If so, what language?  If not, it's not a programming question.

Comment: What Moron decided this question was offensive?  Also for that matter why was it voted down?  READ THE FAQ.  @Cletus, how about making constructive edits to the question like Graeme Perrow.  Finding out the type of file system in code is obviously useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
function string get_FileSystem( strPath )
  object objFSO, objDrive;
begin
  set objFSO = CreateObject ( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
  if ( IsObject (objFSO) ) then
    try
      set objDrive = objFSO.GetDrive( objFSO.GetDriveName( strPath ) );
      if ( IsObject( objDrive ) ) then
        //Available return types include FAT, NTFS, FAT, FAT32, and CDFS
        return objDrive.FileSystem;
      endif;
    catch
      MessageBox( "Unable to determine File System.", INFORMATION );
    endcatch;
  endif;
end;
```

that's from http://kb.acresso.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107782

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(new DriveInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory).DriveFormat);
```

C#

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the drive in Explorer, choose Properties. The filesystem should be displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Win32 api : Win32 FAQ since 1992 !

(see news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32)

Comment: Don't believe this answer. There is no FAQ for that newsgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Here are code which may help you

```
foreach (DriveInfo objDrive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
        Response.Write("</br>Drive Type : " + objDrive.Name);
        Response.Write("</br>Drive Type : " + objDrive.DriveType.ToString());
        Response.Write("</br>Available Free Space : " + objDrive.AvailableFreeSpace.ToString() + "(bytes)");
        Response.Write("</br>Drive Format : " + objDrive.DriveFormat);
        Response.Write("</br>Total Free Space : " + objDrive.TotalFreeSpace.ToString() + "(bytes)");
        Response.Write("</br>Total Size : " + objDrive.TotalSize.ToString() + "(bytes)");
        Response.Write("</br>Volume Label : " + objDrive.VolumeLabel);
        Response.Write("</br></br>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant Win32 and not .NET, see the WinAPI GetVolumeInformation() function. You can find it documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com